# Paypal Checkout REST API server side code not clear

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

**Background**

I am selling on-line live courses where a user can purchase for example 5 live classes. My site is built with CodeIgniter and my checkout page looks like this:

[image]

My main payment option is the Stripe gateway which I successfully integrated yesterday with minimal hassle. I am using Stripe.js and submitting to a hidden form which pops up with the Stripe payment form and then redirects to a processor controller...

PayPal on the other hand is a NIGHTMARE. I am confused as to which API I should choose...

[image]

Checkout REST is apparently their most modern and up-to-date option for custom integration... this is what the PayPal documentation says:

> The enhanced PayPal Express Checkout with In-Context gives your
>   customers a simplified checkout experience that keeps them local to
>   your website throughout the payment authorization process and lets
>   them use their PayPal balance, bank account, or credit card to pay
>   without sharing or entering any sensitive information on your site.

Fantastic...

**What I have tried**

I am at the [Enable In-Context Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/enable-in-context-checkout/) step and this is where I get lost due to the lack of any server-side code examples.

I have added the example code as follows.

```
<!-- paypal payment -->
<form id="myContainer" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url() . 'paypal/process'; ?>"></form>
<script>
window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
    paypal.checkout.setup('MY-MERCHANT-ID-HERE', {
        environment: 'sandbox',
        container: 'myContainer'
    });
};
</script>
<script src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>
<!-- end paypal payment -->
```

**Problems**

When I click the PayPal button then whatever I echoed in the form action url (paypal/process) shows up in the popup... so if i put...

```
class Paypal extends MX_Controller
{
    public function process()
    {
        echo '<h1>test</h1>';
    }
}
```

Then when I click the PayPal button I get this....

[image]

It should be the login-to-paypal window, but it is showing my controller data!

**Question(s):**

What should I be putting in my controller? Further to the point, where is that information to be found on paypal's mess of a documentation website?

**Endnote**

Stripe was just so intuitive, I could add my data to their popup form so easily just by echoing the order data into their javascript function... but paypal is clear as mud at this point.

Comment: Closer but still no cigar, this link should be the first link in paypals 'developer' documentation: http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/

Comment: I got Stripe up and running so quickly, it was actually enjoyable. Not a word used often in eCommerce. PayPal's documentation is confusing, incomplete, and often misleading. It's exhausting. I'll keep an eye on this, I hope you get a solution!

Comment: I actually did manage it in the end... let me dig up what I did...

Comment: This is basically the code that I have used... I installed the paypal SDK/API with composer and followed the code examples. http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/

Comment: paypal is still mud? i also think stripe is more clear, anyway i want to know how do you think paypal is still mud or some updated.